# Looking to reorder a Map

Tags: java

I have a java Map

```
Map<String, Attributes>
```

String will be an application name, and attributes will be the attributes associated. (Attributes is a custom type).  I need to reorder this Map based on user subscriptions.  I am thinking along the lines of

1. finding the applications the user has subscribed to
2. creating another Map
3. looking for each of these applications in the original Map and copying the values to the new Map in the new order

Can someone help me as to how to implement this?  And even if this is the best way to tackle this?

Many thanks!

Ok adding an edit to clarify some of the comments.

The original map holds all of the available apps, it will look something like:

```
"app1", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
"app2", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
"app3", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
"app4", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
```

If a user has subscribed to app2 and app4, I want to reorder it to:

```
"app2", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
"app4", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
"app1", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
"app3", "attribute1, attribute2, attribute3"
```

so that their subscribed apps are at the top of the list (the list is used to populate a Spring JSP page).  So when a user sees the page of apps, they can first see what they have and below what else is available.

Comment: What do you mean in "new order"? Do you need to iterate through Map keys in predictable order? If yes, `SortedMap` or `NavigableMap` may suit your needs. If no, please, elaborate (perhaps, you meant "filter" instead of "reorder")?

Comment: Echoing Viktor - Maps *generally* don't have an explicitly defined order, because you normally use them to look up values based on a specific key.  If you're not going to be doing any key-based lookups, then perhaps you don't need this to be a Map after all... something to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) may be what you are looking for. It retains the insertion order of items, but still allows you to look them up using their key.

If you put the items in to the LinkedHashMap in the order you wish them to be in, they will remain in that order when you call .values() on the map.

Answer (score 2):

A Map is an unordered collection. If you need the Attribute(s) in an order I suggest you add them to a List and order them using a custom comparator.
e.g.

```
Map<String, Attributes> map =
List<Attributes> list = new ArrayList<Attributes>(map.values());
Collections.sort(list, myComparator);
```

You can use a SortedMap if all you want to do is sort based on the key, but since it appears you want to have list as the end result, "subscribed apps are at the top of the list" why not sort them as a list?

Comment: Downvote for reinventing the wheel.  Treemap or SortedMap will do this for you.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Actually no, a SortedMap will sort the keys, not the values.

Comment: @Christoffer yes I am aware.  Based on OP: `String will be an application name`  and `finding the applications the user has subscribed to` .  Granted his question is not fully baked

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Peter is sorting on values though, which SortedMap does not do.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, when you have a generic table of attribute, you may want to sort of any column.

Comment: The OP states "subscribed apps are at the top of the list" as it will be turned into a list as some point, why not sort them as a list?

Comment: @Peter his modification came quite some time after my initial viewing of this page

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) as opposed to just a basic Map. Google for "SortedMap examples" and you'll find plenty of helpful examples.

Comment: A SortedMap can only sort on the key, not the value.

Comment: Agreed, but I think he's honestly looking for retrieval from the Map based on key, not sorting it. This is assuming that "subscription" is the key.

Comment: Thanks guys.Yes, I want to search based on the "String" part of the map (the key) which is the application name.

Answer (score 0):

Maps are generally not ordered, but you can use a [TreeMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for an ordered map (actually a [SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html)). You would create it passing a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) into the constructor:

```
Map<String,Attributes> myMap = new TreeMap<String,Attributes>(myComparator);
```

This also allows for quick traversal of the map through its iterator in the order specified by the Comparator.

```
Comparator<String> myComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String str1, string str2) {
        return str1.compareTo(str2); 
    }
};
```

Now add values to your map:

```
myMap.put(userAttr.getFieldToOrderBy(), userAttr);
```

It will insert the new entry into the correct place in the tree.

Comment: I realize it's just an example, but you should probably note that that Comparator is redundant as it performs the same default comparison as used by the TreeMap when no comparator is specified.

Answer (score 0):

The hidden answer is to rethink your design.

You should have a class `Application` containing fields `String name` and `Attributes attributes`, then `User` would have `User.getSubscribedApplications()` which returns a `List<Application>`.

And `Attributes` should probably be `Set<Attribute>`.